# how to dynamically populate a drop down box in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

have two drop down box, want when a user selects an option in the first drop down box, the second drop down box options will show options based on what was selected in the first drop down box. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it with javascript, as JSP is server side templating technology for generating pages on server side. For altering pages and add behavior on client side, you have to use JavaScript.

I reccomend using some JS framework such as [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), so you won´t have to reinvent the wheel for common tasks.

You can find a post about populating dropdown in JQuery here

> [Populate a select dropdown list with jQuery](http://devingredients.com/2011/05/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-with-jquery/)